# How Prolog's logical update view works for assert and retract?

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog, prolog-assert

Can someone please explain the Prolog logical view about assert and retract in details?

For example in code below, in the first run Prolog returns true and in subsequent runs returns false. I don't know why because of Prolog logical view when  `asserta(nextBound(100))` satisfies, nice(X) is still frozen with values when it started so this change should be ignore  and `nextbound(100)` must be false.

```
nextBound(10000).

nice(X) :-
   asserta(nextBound(100)),
   retract(nextBound(10000)),
   nextBound(100).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a `trace` to determine what happens:

```
| ?- nice(_).
      1    1  Call: nice(_17) ?
      2    2  Call: asserta(nextBound(100)) ?
      2    2  Exit: asserta(nextBound(100)) ?   <-- 1st assert of netBound(100) succeeds
      3    2  Call: retract(nextBound(10000)) ?
      3    2  Exit: retract(nextBound(10000)) ? <-- retract nextBound(10000) succeeds
      4    2  Call: nextBound(100) ?
      4    2  Exit: nextBound(100) ? <-- Succeeds because netBound(100) now a fact
      1    1  Exit: nice(_17) ?

(1 ms) yes
{trace}
| ?- nice(_).
      1    1  Call: nice(_17) ?
      2    2  Call: asserta(nextBound(100)) ?
      2    2  Exit: asserta(nextBound(100)) ?   <-- 2nd assert of netBound(100) succeeds
      3    2  Call: retract(nextBound(10000)) ?
      3    2  Fail: retract(nextBound(10000)) ? <-- retract nextBound(10000) fails
      1    1  Fail: nice(_17) ?

(3 ms) no
{trace}
| ?-
```

You can see that, in the first case, first the `nextBound(100)` fact is successfully asserted (for the 1st time). Then, the `retract(nextBound(10000))` succeeds because `nextBound(10000).` is a fact which exists in the data. Following that, the query `nextBound(100)` succeeds because two steps before this fact was asserted into the data.

On the second execution of `nice(_)`, `nextBound(10000)` doesn't exist because it was retracted in the first execution, and the code doesn't re-assert it. So, in the second execution of `nice(_)`, `retract(nextBound(10000))` fails because the fact `nextBound(10000)` doesn't exist and the entire second execution of `nice(_)` fails at that point since backtracking over `asserta` and `retract` do not re-execute and produce additional results.

A listing shows that now there are two `nextBound(100)` facts, since we've asserted one in each of the two runs of `nice(_)`, and no `nextBound(10000)` since it was retracted in the first run of `nice(_)`:

```
| ?- listing.

% file: user

nice(_) :-
        asserta(nextBound(100)),
        retract(nextBound(10000)),
        nextBound(100).

% file: user_input

nextBound(100).
nextBound(100).

(1 ms) yes
| ?-
```

The logical update view, as stated in the SWI documentation, says, *Starting with SWI-Prolog 3.3.0 we adhere to the logical update view, where backtrackable predicates that **enter the definition of a predicate** will not see any changes (either caused by `assert/1` or `retract/1`) **to the predicate**.*

In other words, the logical update view prevents the predicate from dynamically changing *itself* while it's executing. That's *not* the scenario here.

In fact, it's critical in Prolog that, during the execution of a predicate, if you assert a fact at one point in the predicate, that result must be visible in it immediately, or the predicate may not be able to function properly. There are many many common library predicates that rely on this behavior.

Comment: thank sir, but i think that because of logical view of prolog "nextBound(100)" should evaluate 'false' by nice(_) in first execution because  asserta(nextBound(100)) done in nice(_) predicate and nice(_) is frozen on that time.isn't it?

Comment: @CoderInNetwork as you can see in the trace, `nextBound(100)` is evaluated and succeeds in the first execution of `nice(_)` as expected because it has been asserted before it is queried.

Comment: @CoderInNetwork, to be clear, when `nice(_)` is executed, it doesn't operate on a *frozen* state of the database. The database is dynamic during the course of execution. Any facts asserted or retracted are done so immediately and subsequent queries see those results. Have I answered your question?

Comment: dear lurker Your answer  is clear but isn't that in contraction with this ?http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=update

Comment: @CoderInNetwork I don't think it's a contradiction. The comment on that link says, *Starting with SWI-Prolog 3.3.0 we adhere to the logical update view, where backtrackable predicates that **enter the definition of a predicate** will not see any changes (either caused by `assert/1` or `retract/1`) **to the predicate**.* In other words, a predicate cannot change it's own definition dynamically. The definition of the predicate itself is static with respect to changes to that predicate in the database. If this were not the case, then it would be a bit chaotic.

Answer (score 5):

To start from a historical view, the logical update view has been first implemented in Quintus 2.0 (whose current successor is SICStus) and described in the literature in 1987. It has been adopted in ISO Prolog ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995. The principal idea is that any goal of a dynamic predicate will take exactly those clauses into account that are present at the point in time when the goal is executed. Any further changes — be they additions or deletions — are not taken into account for the execution of that very goal.

Prior to the logical update view, there have been various more or less consistent implementations, most were incompatible with various optimizations for Prolog systems. Note that the difference only shows if you have goals  that may have more than one answer. Either as a simple goal, or when using retract **and** you are using `retract/1` or `assertz/1`. The difference does not show when using `asserta/1` only. So your example cannot clarify the differences.

Consider a dynamic predicate `p/1`. Since the following interaction is using the toplevel only, I will make `p/1` known to the system by asserting a fact and immediately retracting all facts of `p/1`.  Also, I will remove all facts with `retractall(p(_))` before starting the next query.

```
?- asserta(p(1)).
   true.  % now p/1 is known to the system.
?- retractall(p(_)), assertz(p(1)), p(X), assertz(p(2)).
   X = 1.  % only one answer!
?- retractall(p(_)), assertz(p(1)), p(X), assertz(p(2)), p(Y).
   X = 1, Y = X
;  X = 1, Y = 2.
```

So the first goal `p(X)` sees only `p(1)`, whereas the second goal `p(Y)` sees both. This applies for any active goal:

```
?- retractall(p(_)), assertz(p(1)), assertz(p(2)), p(X), assertz(p(3)), p(Y).
   X = 1, Y = X
;  X = 1, Y = 2
;  X = 1, Y = 3
;  X = 2, Y = 1
;  X = 2, Y = X
;  X = 2, Y = 3
;  X = 2, Y = 3
;  false.
```

Again, note that `X` is only 1 or 2 but not 3.

Alternatively, you can imagine that each goal `p(X)` is replaced by:

```
... findall(Xi, p(Xi), Xis), member(X, Xis) ...
```

This shows you a bit the idea behind: Conceptually, all answers are stored temporally, and only then each answer is shown.

Er, above is not quite true, for only the *clauses* of `p/1` are handled this way. That is, as long as you are storing only facts, above explanation is perfect, but should you also store rules, you would need a more complex explanation, roughly:

```
 ... findall(Xi-Bi, clause(p(Xi),Bi), XiBis), member(X-B,XiBis), B ...
```

And, again, this is not the plain truth, for some more exotic issues like cuts might intervene. I will leave it that way for the moment<sup>1</sup>.

Similarly, `retract/1` will also see and delete the clauses it sees at the point in time of executing it. For most situations this is quite intuitive and agrees with our expectations. Nevertheless, there are quite absurd situations as the following:

```
?- retractall(p(_)),
   assertz(p(1)), assertz(p(2)),
   retract(p(X)), ( X = 1, retract(p(Y)) ; X = 2, Y = none ).
   X = 1, Y = 2
;  X = 2, Y = none.
```

Here, the fact `p(2)` was deleted twice, although the data base contained only a single fact `p(2).`

---

### Footnotes

1 Actually, replace

```
... p(X) ...
```

by

```
... findall(Xi-Bi, clause(p(Xi),Bi), XiBis), answs_goal_x(XiBis,X, G), G ...
```

with

```
answs_goal_x([], _, true).
answs_goal_x([Xi-Bi|XiBis], X, ( X = Xi, Bi ; G) ) :-
   answs_goal_x(XiBis, X, G).
```

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer. The historical info and examples are quite helpful. (+1)